# Why is the output the same when I use different encodings on Node.js using fs.readFileSync()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, solidity, fs

I am trying to understand why when I use the readFileSync method and use different encodings (for example utf-8, hex, ascii) I have the same output on the console and when I dont pass any specific encoding I receive the output in utf-8 format.

I mean, shouldn’t I receive the info of the file on the file format (in this case .sol) If I dont specify any encoding and receive the info on utf-8 format If I specify utf-8 format?

I think there is something I am not understanding about how enconding works.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc')

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
```

Comment: Well, it depends upon what's actually in the data.  utf-8 and ascii are identical if the file contains nothing but characters 0-127 as those are the same in utf-8 and ascii.  Only when you go above 127, do you get multi-byte representations that need to be interpreted differently and will generate a different result if interpreted as utf-8 vs. ascii.  Utf-8 is a variable byte system (from 1 to 4 bytes) that can represent all 1,112,064 code points in unicode.  For 0-127, it uses one byte and the value is identical to its ascii code.  Above that, it takes more than one byte.

Comment: What does `Inbox.sol` actually contain?  It is just ascii text?

Comment: Please don't just post and disappear.  I engaged, gave you some feedback, asked you some questions and now you're gone.  This makes it a lot harder for you to attract people to help you.

Comment: I am so sorry, this is my first time posting on stackoverflow, I didnt know people help me so quickly :) Thank you so much for your quick response.

Comment: Yes, Inbox.sol contain only ascii text.

Comment: What I cant understand is why when I call fs.readFileSync() without specifing any encoding I should received the Inbox.sol in raw buffer but I receive an error: 'No input sources specified.'

Comment: If you don't specify an encoding, then `fs.readFileSync()` returns a Buffer object that doesn't apply any encoding to it.  You just get the raw data.

Comment: If you mean that you get `'No input sources specified.` from your `solc.compile()`, then that's probably because that function is expecting a string and you're passing it a Buffer object, not a string.  So, you need to pass an encoding or you need to convert the Buffer to a string so you have a string to pass to `solc.compile()`.

Comment: Ohh perfect, I understand. And when you say raw data, for example If the buffer is returning this <Buffer 54 65 73 74 69 6e 67 20 4e 6f 64 65 2e 6a 73 20 72 65 61 64 46 69 6c 65 28 29>  is this ASCII? or what is it?

Comment: That is raw binary data in a Buffer object.  You have to apply an encoding of some type to make it into a Javascript string as in `source.toString('utf8')`, but if you're going to do that, you may as well just pass that encoding directly to `fs.readFileSync()`  as in `fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8')` so the encoding is already applied upon reading and it's already in string format.

Comment: Sorry If this is a stupid question but raw binary data isnt only 0 and 1?

Comment: At the level of the computer itself it is only consecutive bits of ones and zeroes, but it's usually displayed in Hex (where each 8 bits are displayed as a hexadecimal number) which is what `<Buffer 54 65 73 74 69 6e 67 20 4e 6f 64 65 2e 6a 73 20 72 65 61 64 46 69 6c 65 28 29>` is showing and is easier for display purposes than the pure ones and zeroes.  You can look in an ascii table and see that the first byte in that buffer which is hex 54 actually corresponds to the letter "T" and if you apply a UTF8 encoding and convert it to a string, the first letter in that string would be a "T".

Comment: Amazing! Thats what I wasnt understanding, now I know its displayed in Hex. I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me, many many thanks @jfriend00 !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call it like this:

```
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');
```

You are passing the utf8 encoding to the function.  It will read the data from the file and apply the encoding to the data to convert it to a string.

If you call it like this with no encoding:

```
console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
```

It will give you the raw binary data in a Buffer object and you will get something that (if you `console.log(source)`) will look like this:

```
<Buffer 54 65 73 74 69 6e 67 20 4e 6f 64 65 2e 6a 73 20 72 65 61 64 46 69 6c 65 28 29>
```

That display of the Buffer data is showing one hexadecimal value for each 8-bits of the binary data (for our viewing convenience).  The `54` at the start of the buffer corresponds to the letter `T` so if you converted that buffer to a string with either the `utf8` or `ascii` encoding, you would get a string that starts with a `T`.

If your data is all made up of characters with character codes less than 128, then interpreting it with utf8 and ascii encoding give identical results.  This is because for characters with codes less than 128, utf8 just uses the code for the character directly.  It's only when character codes get higher than 128 that utf8 starts using more than one byte for the character (in fact, it can use 1-4 bytes depending upon the actual code).  There are 1,112,064 code points in unicode.  Since you can only represent 256 unique values in a single byte, it obviously takes more than one byte to represent all 1,112,064 code points in unicode.  When using utf8, that is a variable length encoding that uses one byte per character for anything with a code less than 128 and once you get above 128, it starts using more than one byte for those characters.

Your function call here:

```
console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
```

is apparently expecting a string in the `source` argument so you HAVE to give it a string.  If you don't pass an encoding like this:

```
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');
```

Then, `source` is a Buffer object (not a string) and the `solc.compile(source, 1)` function does not like that and gives you an error.  You apparently need to pass that function a string.  So, the code you show in your question:

```
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
```

is properly getting a string from `fs.readFileSync()` and then passing that string to `solc.compile()`.